# reactjs ToDo List- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following the ReactJS tutorial (http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) for the basic todo list and tweaking it to my liking, but am running into the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Here is the code:

ConfigList.js -

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import ConfigItem from '../components/ConfigItem';


const ConfigList = ({ configs }) => (
  <ul>
    {configs.map(config =>
      <ConfigItem
        key={config.id}
        />
    )}
  </ul>
);

ConfigList.propTypes = {
  configs: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }))
};

export default ConfigList;
```

ConfigItem.js -

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

const ConfigItem = ({ text }) => (
  <li>{text}</li>
);

ConfigItem.propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default ConfigItem;
```

I'm new to ReactJS and somewhat new to Javascript so I'm hoping I get some feedback as to why I'm seeing this error, and what steps I can take to get past it.

Comment: Where is the code that creates a ConfigList component instance?

Answer (score 2):

The error `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` is saying that you're trying to call `map()` on something which doesn't exist. The only place you're calling `map()` is in `ConfigList`:

```
{configs.map(config =>
  <ConfigItem
    key={config.id}
    />
)}
```

which suggests that the `configs` variable hasn't been set when you're trying to call `map()`. Since `ConfigList` is a [functional React component](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components), `configs` is expected to be passed in as part of the `props` object, but it doesn't look like this is being set.

You'll need to check the code where you're calling `<ConfigList />` to make sure you are setting `configs`; it should look a bit like

```
<ConfigList configs={ myConfigs } />
```